# MySQL QUERY runs on localhost, but does not on server

Tags: mysql, localhost

I have this `QUERY`:

```
select 
    a.* 
from 
    mt_proyecto a,
    mt_mockup b,
    mt_diseno c,
    mt_modulo d
where
    a.estado = 'A'  and
    (
        (b.encargado = '1' and b.idproyecto = a.idmtproyecto) or
        (c.encargado = '1' and c.idproyecto = a.idmtproyecto) or
        (d.encargado = '1' and d.idproyecto = a.idmtproyecto)
    )
group by
    a.idmtproyecto

order by a.finalizado asc, a.feccrea desc
```

Result:

[image]

Then, I run the same code on server with the same database:

[image]

Is there any problem with the `query`?

Comment: I believe you have some permission issues.

Comment: Are you sure they both have the same data?

Comment: Might be on server you don't have data like at your local.

Comment: Maybe the query... Can i do it in other way ?

Comment: What does the GROUP BY do?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the query is running correctly on your server, and returning no rows. Please make sure you have the same table contents on your local machine and your server.

Other things:

Pro tip: never use `SELECT *` or `SELECT table.*` in software. Always enumerate the columns you want in your result set.

Unless you use `GROUP BY` with aggregate functions like `SUM()` or `COUNT(), and naming the correct columns from the result set, it returns unpredictable results. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this `QUERY`:

```
select
    a.*
from
(
    mt_proyecto a
    left join mt_mockup b on
    b.idproyecto = a.idmtproyecto
    left join mt_diseno c on
    c.idproyecto = a.idmtproyecto
    left join mt_modulo d on
    d.idproyecto = a.idmtproyecto
    left join mt_integracion e on
    e.idproyecto = a.idmtproyecto
    left join mt_pruebas_internas f on
    f.idproyecto = a.idmtproyecto
)
where
    a.estado = 'A' and 
    (
        (a.idmtproyecto = b.idproyecto and
         b.encargado = '1' ) or
        (a.idmtproyecto = c.idproyecto and
         c.encargado = '1' ) or
        (a.idmtproyecto = d.idproyecto and
         d.encargado = '1' ) or
        (a.idmtproyecto = e.idproyecto and
         e.encargado = '1' ) or
        (a.idmtproyecto = f.idproyecto =
         f.encargado = '1' )
    )

group by a.idmtproyecto

order by
    a.finalizado asc, a.feccrea desc
```

Thanks everyone for answer me. I'll do your suggestions .